# .htaccess code to redirect main domain to dir without url change

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, masking

Here's my situation. I have a legacy website in the root folder of my public_html. This is cumbersome because I have other subdomains and addon domains to manage. So I've designed a web 2.0 website to replace the legacy one, and here is my problematic.

Legacy Website
http://www.annexation.ca/

New Website
http://www.annexation.ca/annexation.ca/

Now what I need to accomplish here, is add some code to .htaccess that will enable the new website to show up with the url of the old one. So I need not only a redirect to the folder, but also a mask that makes the website show up as it did before.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?annexation\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^annexation\.ca /annexation.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava, it worked wonders everything is top notch now!